# Sort WordPress comments in Swift by date and parent comment

Tags: ios, swift, wordpress, sorting

I have a set of comments to an article for a WordPress site stored as objects in an iOS application. Some of the key properties of the Comment-object is:

```
public let id: Int //Unique identifier of comment
public let parentID: Int //ID of the comment this comment is replying to. If it is a top level comment the value is 0.
public let dateCreated: Date //The date the comment was created
```

I wish to display these comments in a `UITableView` the same way it is on WordPress website (and most other websites), where the comments are sorted by date, but the child-comments show under their parents, also sorted by date if there are multiple replies to a single comment. The easiest way to present the comments seems to have a single section `UITableView` with one row per comment, where child-comments will be indented to indicate that they are replying to other comments (again, same design as WordPress and most other websites)

I am struggling to find some sensible code to sort the comments this way. I have been able to make multilevel sorting by sorting first by parentID, then by date, but this does not provide the correct result (replies to comments show at the bottom of the list rather than after their parent comment):

```
var sortedComments = comments.sorted { //comments is the array of comment-objects
    if $0.parentID != $1.parentID {
        return $0.parentID < $1.parentID
    } else {
        return $0.dateCreated < $1.dateCreated
    }
}
```

I guess the algorithm behind this can be reused regardless of programming language, so if someone has an algorithm regardless of programming language that is appreciated (but hey, if someone has a specific Swift-answer I don't mind!)

Comment: What about using on section per parent + children comment? This could simplify you sort, no? Creating sections first, then adding an array of child to each parent?

Comment: If there was only one sub-level that could work (in which case some simple hard coding to deal with that would work for a single section as well), but as you can comment on comments of comments and so on this would not solve the problem.

Comment: The problem with your code example is that your are missing a comparison between id and parentID, that is to connect parent with children. I tried to write a closure with this in mind but so far I have failed.

Comment: Yes, I realised that the code is flawed, but unfortunately I can't seem to come up with a solution :( As this is how the WordPress API is outputting the content I am a bit surprised that there seems to be no (easy to find) answer out there.